# Как включить графическое окружение gnome на ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, настройка, gnome

Поставил на виртуальную машину Ubuntu 18.04. Это моя первая Linux-система, поэтому прошу помощи в настройке.

Установил пакеты LightDM и Gnome. Но графический интерфейс не включен. Какие команды нужно ввести, чтобы активировать UI Gnome?

Comment: Для запуска вручную startx

Comment: `systemctl start lightdm`?